# Search in youtube by using youtube api

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

I need to retrieve videos that contain some topic in title or description , 
I use the following request

```
    https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=???&channelId=???&key=???
```

it return result that not related to the query that I mentioned

Where is the problem?
How api retrieve the result ??

Comment: what do q and channelId equal?

Comment: for example if we need to search about videos that contain keyword obra in skynews channel so we request the following link    https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=obra&channelId=UCoMdktPbSTixAyNGwb-UYkQ               and the result be as as in the following link https://www.youtube.com/user/skynews/search?query=Obra    , result videos didn't contain this keywords in it's title or description

Comment: hmm the API is working correctly, looks like there might be a problem with YouTube Search

Comment: Is there a technique that I can use to retrieve only videos that contains the keyword ?